# Getting Maximum Duration for Each Status

Tags: sql-server

I have been asked to provide a daily report that has the maximum duration; the calculation should start from the last action taken and end with current date for those requests that has not been finalized yet (i.e. accepted, rejected).

My table basically has the following:

```
HitoryID |    RequestID   | Action Taken | StatusID
```

So I started with getting the last action date for every request and used datediff to get the maximum value; however, when I group by the requestID and status ID it gives all records not maximum value per status. We have 6 distinct statuses:

```
1- Not sunmitted
2- Submitted
3- Assigned
4- Reviewed
5 - Accepted
6- Rejected
```

So what I should finally have is 3 records (since I am counting not finalized requests) all with its max duration

Sample Data

```
+-----------+-----------+----------+--------------+
| HistoryID | RequestID | StatusID | Action Taken |
+-----------+-----------+----------+--------------+
|         1 |         1 |        1 | 2/2/2014     |
|         2 |         1 |        2 | 2/2/2014     |
|         3 |         1 |        3 | 2/2/2014     |
|         4 |         1 |        4 | 2/5/2014     |
|         5 |         1 |        5 | 2/4/2014     |
|         6 |         2 |        1 | 12/19/2013   |
|         7 |         2 |        2 | 12/18/2013   |
|         8 |         2 |        3 | 12/18/2013   |
|         9 |         2 |        4 | 12/17/2013   |
|        10 |         2 |        6 | 12/17/2013   |
+-----------+-----------+----------+--------------+
```

Your help is highly appreciated

Comment: Provide some sample data.. so that SO may help you quickly

Comment: And there is no date column in your table

Comment: Please give sample data.

Comment: Data Type: HistoryID int, REquestID: int, ActionTaken: Dateformat, StatusID: int

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way.. I have prepared a set having max of Action Taken for each RequestId and Joined it to table.

```
SELECT T1.HitoryID,REQ_MX.RequestID, REQ_MX.[Action Taken], T1.StatusID
FROM TABLE1 T1
INNER JOIN 
(
SELECT RequestID,MAX([Action Taken]) [Action Taken] FROM TABLE1
GROUP BY RequestID
)REQ_MX ON T1.RequestID = REQ_MX.RequestID 
AND T1.[Action Taken]= REQ_MX.[Action Taken]
```

**Edit:**

> how do I get the max per status and get the associated information with it

The same way as above

```
SELECT T1.HitoryID,REQ_MX.RequestID, REQ_MX.[StatusID],T1.[Action Taken]
FROM TABLE1 T1
INNER JOIN 
(
SELECT RequestID,MAX([StatusID])as [StatusID] FROM TABLE1
GROUP BY RequestID
)REQ_MX ON T1.RequestID = REQ_MX.RequestID 
AND T1.[StatusID]= REQ_MX.[StatusID]
```

Comment: Thanks for your information. Now this is where I got stuck how do I get the max per status and get the associated information with it.

Comment: Thanks for your help Shakeer! Shakeer how can I get the max of each status as the final result should be 3 rows only

Comment: Oh I misunderstood. This could be easy if you provide output. Could you please give desired output @user2597012

Comment: How comes you will get 3 records? because there are more than 3 status types. and how you can say it is max? @user2597012

Comment: Well I am only counting max duration for statuses that are not finalized only .

Comment: Include desired output in your question @user2597012